# CSS px VS Android dp

Tags: android, css, graphics

I am making a project which requires a consistent coordinate system between different platforms. If the unit of the coordinate system was a CSS 'px' is it appropriate for me to use an Android 'dp'? If not, how do I convert the Android dp so that they are both physically the same size?

What I am asking in the endis: Is the physical space used by one CSS 'px' the same space used by one Android 'dp'?

Comment: No, but they're similar.  One dp is 1/160th of an inch, approximately.  So laying out in dp is equivalent to laying out in inches (physical space).  As for converting to px-  you shouldn't.  Create an appropriate layout for Android using all the tools available.  You especially should not be using dp at all for large amounts of space-  you should only be using it to add small padding between items, and be using linear and relative layouts for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Gabe Sechan has given the answer already.

Both px and dp are pixel density indepdent units. But the correspondence of on 1 virtual pixel denominated in px and denominated in dp is different.

For the DP, 
https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html

1 dp is one pixel in a screen that has density of 160 pixel per inch.
If your screen has twice that density, e.g. 320 pixels per inch with one dp you would consume 2 pixels on that screen.

when you go to a desktop, 1 px 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

pixels (1px = 1/96th of 1in)

So your base density, when thinking in pixels is a screen with 96 pixels per inch. So lower density screens - as the screens are way bigger, you do not need such base high density.

In summary. One unit is 1/160th of an inch. And the other 1/96th of an inch.  If you want to make something one inch big you use 96 px. Or you use 160 dp.

But desktop app that looks the same as an adroid app, normally looks quite bad. Sorry bug, if you want to support android phones and desktop users, I think you are going to have to write twice the screens, no matter how much you bootstrap it ... Does Gmail on mobile look anything like gmail on your browser? It can-t right...